# Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Socket')

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, heroku, whatsapp

i have a problem on heroku:

`Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Socket')`

i know the solution is change STREAM for Socket in the file Injected.js of whatsapp-web.js. but i dont know how to modify this node_modules file in heroku or how to upload this change in heroku because if i try to upload all node modules i cant

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the patch update [`1.16.5`](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/pull/1362), so simply update your `package.json` file

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve it was uninstall the whatsapp-web.js library and installed it again. I noticed that it does some additional config modification with puppeteer.js

Comment: updated "whatsapp-web.js": "^1.16.4"

Answer (score 0):

for multi device use this code for Injected.js

```
'use strict';

// Exposes the internal Store to the WhatsApp Web client
exports.ExposeStore = (moduleRaidStr) => {
    eval('var moduleRaid = ' + moduleRaidStr);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    window.mR = moduleRaid();
    window.Store = Object.assign({}, window.mR.findModule(m => m.default && m.default.Chat)[0].default);
    window.Store.AppState = window.mR.findModule('Socket')[0].Socket;
    window.Store.Conn = window.mR.findModule('Conn')[0].Conn;
    window.Store.BlockContact = window.mR.findModule('blockContact')[0];
    window.Store.Call = window.mR.findModule('CallCollection')[0].CallCollection;
    window.Store.Cmd = window.mR.findModule('Cmd')[0].Cmd;
    window.Store.CryptoLib = window.mR.findModule('decryptE2EMedia')[0];
    window.Store.DownloadManager = window.mR.findModule('downloadManager')[0].downloadManager;
    window.Store.Features = window.mR.findModule('FEATURE_CHANGE_EVENT')[0].GK;
   //window.Store.genId = window.mR.findModule('newTag')[0].newTag;
    window.Store.genId = window.mR.findModule('newTag')?.[0]?.newTag || null;
    //
    window.Store.GroupMetadata = window.mR.findModule((module) => module.default && module.default.handlePendingInvite)[0].default;
    window.Store.Invite = window.mR.findModule('sendJoinGroupViaInvite')[0];
    window.Store.InviteInfo = window.mR.findModule('sendQueryGroupInvite')[0];
    window.Store.Label = window.mR.findModule('LabelCollection')[0].LabelCollection;
    window.Store.MediaPrep = window.mR.findModule('MediaPrep')[0];
    window.Store.MediaObject = window.mR.findModule('getOrCreateMediaObject')[0];
    window.Store.NumberInfo = window.mR.findModule('formattedPhoneNumber')[0];
    window.Store.MediaTypes = window.mR.findModule('msgToMediaType')[0];
    window.Store.MediaUpload = window.mR.findModule('uploadMedia')[0];
    window.Store.MsgKey = window.mR.findModule((module) => module.default && module.default.fromString)[0].default;
    window.Store.MessageInfo = window.mR.findModule('sendQueryMsgInfo')[0];
    window.Store.OpaqueData = window.mR.findModule(module => module.default && module.default.createFromData)[0].default;
   // window.Store.QueryExist = window.mR.findModule(module => typeof module.default === 'function' && module.default.toString().includes('Should not reach queryExists MD'))[0].default;
    window.Store.QueryExist = window.mR.findModule(module => typeof module.default === 'function' && module.default.toString().includes('Should not reach'))[0].default;
    //
    window.Store.QueryProduct = window.mR.findModule('queryProduct')[0];
    window.Store.QueryOrder = window.mR.findModule('queryOrder')[0];
    window.Store.SendClear = window.mR.findModule('sendClear')[0];
    window.Store.SendDelete = window.mR.findModule('sendDelete')[0];
    window.Store.SendMessage = window.mR.findModule('addAndSendMsgToChat')[0];
    window.Store.SendSeen = window.mR.findModule('sendSeen')[0];
    window.Store.Sticker = window.mR.findModule('Sticker')[0].Sticker;
    window.Store.User = window.mR.findModule('getMaybeMeUser')[0];
    window.Store.UploadUtils = window.mR.findModule((module) => (module.default && module.default.encryptAndUpload) ? module.default : null)[0].default;
    window.Store.UserConstructor = window.mR.findModule((module) => (module.default && module.default.prototype && module.default.prototype.isServer && module.default.prototype.isUser) ? module.default : null)[0].default;
    window.Store.Validators = window.mR.findModule('findLinks')[0];
    window.Store.VCard = window.mR.findModule('vcardFromContactModel')[0];
    window.Store.Wap = window.mR.findModule('queryLinkPreview')[0].default;
    window.Store.WidFactory = window.mR.findModule('createWid')[0];
    window.Store.getProfilePicFull = window.mR.findModule('getProfilePicFull')[0].getProfilePicFull;
    window.Store.PresenceUtils = window.mR.findModule('sendPresenceAvailable')[0];
    window.Store.ChatState = window.mR.findModule('sendChatStateComposing')[0];
    window.Store.GroupParticipants = window.mR.findModule('sendPromoteParticipants')[0];
    window.Store.JoinInviteV4 = window.mR.findModule('sendJoinGroupViaInviteV4')[0];
    window.Store.findCommonGroups = window.mR.findModule('findCommonGroups')[0].findCommonGroups;
    window.Store.StatusUtils = window.mR.findModule('setMyStatus')[0];
    window.Store.StickerTools = {
        ...window.mR.findModule('toWebpSticker')[0],
        ...window.mR.findModule('addWebpMetadata')[0]
    };
  
    window.Store.GroupUtils = {
        ...window.mR.findModule('sendCreateGroup')[0],
        ...window.mR.findModule('sendSetGroupSubject')[0],
        ...window.mR.findModule('markExited')[0]
    };

    if (!window.Store.Chat._find) {
        window.Store.Chat._find = e => {
            const target = window.Store.Chat.get(e);
            return target ? Promise.resolve(target) : Promise.resolve({
                id: e
            });
        };
    }
};

exports.LoadUtils = () => {
    if(!window.Store.genId) {
        window.Store.genId = window.Store.MsgKey.newId;
    }
    window.WWebJS = {};

    window.WWebJS.sendSeen = async (chatId) => {
        let chat = window.Store.Chat.get(chatId);
        if (chat !== undefined) {
            await window.Store.SendSeen.sendSeen(chat, false);
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    };

    window.WWebJS.sendMessage = async (chat, content, options = {}) => {
        let attOptions = {};
        if (options.attachment) {
            attOptions = options.sendMediaAsSticker
                ? await window.WWebJS.processStickerData(options.attachment)
                : await window.WWebJS.processMediaData(options.attachment, {
                    forceVoice: options.sendAudioAsVoice,
                    forceDocument: options.sendMediaAsDocument,
                    forceGif: options.sendVideoAsGif
                });

            content = options.sendMediaAsSticker ? undefined : attOptions.preview;

            delete options.attachment;
            delete options.sendMediaAsSticker;
        }

        let quotedMsgOptions = {};
        if (options.quotedMessageId) {
            let quotedMessage = window.Store.Msg.get(options.quotedMessageId);
            if (quotedMessage.canReply()) {
                quotedMsgOptions = quotedMessage.msgContextInfo(chat);
            }
            delete options.quotedMessageId;
        }

        if (options.mentionedJidList) {
            options.mentionedJidList = options.mentionedJidList.map(cId => window.Store.Contact.get(cId).id);
        }

        let locationOptions = {};
        if (options.location) {
            locationOptions = {
                type: 'location',
                loc: options.location.description,
                lat: options.location.latitude,
                lng: options.location.longitude
            };
            delete options.location;
        }

        let vcardOptions = {};
        if (options.contactCard) {
            let contact = window.Store.Contact.get(options.contactCard);
            vcardOptions = {
                body: window.Store.VCard.vcardFromContactModel(contact).vcard,
                type: 'vcard',
                vcardFormattedName: contact.formattedName
            };
            delete options.contactCard;
        } else if (options.contactCardList) {
            let contacts = options.contactCardList.map(c => window.Store.Contact.get(c));
            let vcards = contacts.map(c => window.Store.VCard.vcardFromContactModel(c));
            vcardOptions = {
                type: 'multi_vcard',
                vcardList: vcards,
                body: undefined
            };
            delete options.contactCardList;
        } else if (options.parseVCards && typeof (content) === 'string' && content.startsWith('BEGIN:VCARD')) {
            delete options.parseVCards;
            try {
                const parsed = window.Store.VCard.parseVcard(content);
                if (parsed) {
                    vcardOptions = {
                        type: 'vcard',
                        vcardFormattedName: window.Store.VCard.vcardGetNameFromParsed(parsed)
                    };
                }
            } catch (_) {
                // not a vcard
            }
        }

        if (options.linkPreview) {
            delete options.linkPreview;

            // Not supported yet by WhatsApp Web on MD
            if(!window.Store.Features.features.MD_BACKEND) {
                const link = window.Store.Validators.findLink(content);
                if (link) {
                    const preview = await window.Store.Wap.queryLinkPreview(link.url);
                    preview.preview = true;
                    preview.subtype = 'url';
                    options = { ...options, ...preview };
                }
            }
        }
        
        let buttonOptions = {};
        if(options.buttons){
            let caption;
            if (options.buttons.type === 'chat') {
                content = options.buttons.body;
                caption = content;
            } else {
                caption = options.caption ? options.caption : ' '; //Caption can't be empty
            }
            buttonOptions = {
                productHeaderImageRejected: false,
                isFromTemplate: false,
                isDynamicReplyButtonsMsg: true,
                title: options.buttons.title ? options.buttons.title : undefined,
                footer: options.buttons.footer ? options.buttons.footer : undefined,
                dynamicReplyButtons: options.buttons.buttons,
                replyButtons: options.buttons.buttons,
                caption: caption
            };
            delete options.buttons;
        }

        let listOptions = {};
        if(options.list){
            if(window.Store.Conn.platform === 'smba' || window.Store.Conn.platform === 'smbi'){
                throw '[LT01] Whatsapp business can\'t send this yet';
            }
            listOptions = {
                type: 'list',
                footer: options.list.footer,
                list: {
                    ...options.list,
                    listType: 1
                },
                body: options.list.description
            };
            delete options.list;
            delete listOptions.list.footer;
        }

        const meUser = window.Store.User.getMaybeMeUser();
        const isMD = window.Store.Features.features.MD_BACKEND;

        const newMsgId = new window.Store.MsgKey({
            from: meUser,
            to: chat.id,
            id: window.Store.genId(),
            participant: isMD && chat.id.isGroup() ? meUser : undefined,
            selfDir: 'out',
        });

        const extraOptions = options.extraOptions || {};
        delete options.extraOptions;

        const ephemeralSettings = {
            ephemeralDuration: chat.isEphemeralSettingOn() ? chat.getEphemeralSetting() : undefined,
            ephemeralSettingTimestamp: chat.getEphemeralSettingTimestamp() || undefined,
            disappearingModeInitiator: chat.getDisappearingModeInitiator() || undefined,
        };

        const message = {
            ...options,
            id: newMsgId,
            ack: 0,
            body: content,
            from: meUser,
            to: chat.id,
            local: true,
            self: 'out',
            t: parseInt(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
            isNewMsg: true,
            type: 'chat',
            ...ephemeralSettings,
            ...locationOptions,
            ...attOptions,
            ...quotedMsgOptions,
            ...vcardOptions,
            ...buttonOptions,
            ...listOptions,
            ...extraOptions
        };

        await window.Store.SendMessage.addAndSendMsgToChat(chat, message);
        return window.Store.Msg.get(newMsgId._serialized);
    };

    window.WWebJS.toStickerData = async (mediaInfo) => {
        if (mediaInfo.mimetype == 'image/webp') return mediaInfo;

        const file = window.WWebJS.mediaInfoToFile(mediaInfo);
        const webpSticker = await window.Store.StickerTools.toWebpSticker(file);
        const webpBuffer = await webpSticker.arrayBuffer();
        const data = window.WWebJS.arrayBufferToBase64(webpBuffer);

        return {
            mimetype: 'image/webp',
            data
        };
    };

    window.WWebJS.processStickerData = async (mediaInfo) => {
        if (mediaInfo.mimetype !== 'image/webp') throw new Error('Invalid media type');

        const file = window.WWebJS.mediaInfoToFile(mediaInfo);
        let filehash = await window.WWebJS.getFileHash(file);
        let mediaKey = await window.WWebJS.generateHash(32);

        const controller = new AbortController();
        const uploadedInfo = await window.Store.UploadUtils.encryptAndUpload({
            blob: file,
            type: 'sticker',
            signal: controller.signal,
            mediaKey
        });

        const stickerInfo = {
            ...uploadedInfo,
            clientUrl: uploadedInfo.url,
            deprecatedMms3Url: uploadedInfo.url,
            uploadhash: uploadedInfo.encFilehash,
            size: file.size,
            type: 'sticker',
            filehash
        };

        return stickerInfo;
    };

    window.WWebJS.processMediaData = async (mediaInfo, { forceVoice, forceDocument, forceGif }) => {
        const file = window.WWebJS.mediaInfoToFile(mediaInfo);
        const mData = await window.Store.OpaqueData.createFromData(file, file.type);
        const mediaPrep = window.Store.MediaPrep.prepRawMedia(mData, { asDocument: forceDocument });
        const mediaData = await mediaPrep.waitForPrep();
        const mediaObject = window.Store.MediaObject.getOrCreateMediaObject(mediaData.filehash);

        const mediaType = window.Store.MediaTypes.msgToMediaType({
            type: mediaData.type,
            isGif: mediaData.isGif
        });

        if (forceVoice && mediaData.type === 'audio') {
            mediaData.type = 'ptt';
        }

        if (forceGif && mediaData.type === 'video') {
            mediaData.isGif = true;
        }

        if (forceDocument) {
            mediaData.type = 'document';
        }

        if (!(mediaData.mediaBlob instanceof window.Store.OpaqueData)) {
            mediaData.mediaBlob = await window.Store.OpaqueData.createFromData(mediaData.mediaBlob, mediaData.mediaBlob.type);
        }

        mediaData.renderableUrl = mediaData.mediaBlob.url();
        mediaObject.consolidate(mediaData.toJSON());
        mediaData.mediaBlob.autorelease();

        const uploadedMedia = await window.Store.MediaUpload.uploadMedia({
            mimetype: mediaData.mimetype,
            mediaObject,
            mediaType
        });

        const mediaEntry = uploadedMedia.mediaEntry;
        if (!mediaEntry) {
            throw new Error('upload failed: media entry was not created');
        }

        mediaData.set({
            clientUrl: mediaEntry.mmsUrl,
            deprecatedMms3Url: mediaEntry.deprecatedMms3Url,
            directPath: mediaEntry.directPath,
            mediaKey: mediaEntry.mediaKey,
            mediaKeyTimestamp: mediaEntry.mediaKeyTimestamp,
            filehash: mediaObject.filehash,
            encFilehash: mediaEntry.encFilehash,
            uploadhash: mediaEntry.uploadHash,
            size: mediaObject.size,
            streamingSidecar: mediaEntry.sidecar,
            firstFrameSidecar: mediaEntry.firstFrameSidecar
        });

        return mediaData;
    };

    window.WWebJS.getMessageModel = message => {
        const msg = message.serialize();

        msg.isEphemeral = message.isEphemeral;
        msg.isStatusV3 = message.isStatusV3;
        msg.links = (message.getLinks()).map(link => ({
            link: link.href,
            isSuspicious: Boolean(link.suspiciousCharacters && link.suspiciousCharacters.size)
        }));

        if (msg.buttons) {
            msg.buttons = msg.buttons.serialize();
        }
        if (msg.dynamicReplyButtons) {
            msg.dynamicReplyButtons = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg.dynamicReplyButtons));
        }
        if (msg.replyButtons) {
            msg.replyButtons = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg.replyButtons));
        }

        if (typeof msg.id.remote === 'object') {
            msg.id = Object.assign({}, msg.id, { remote: msg.id.remote._serialized });
        }

        delete msg.pendingAckUpdate;

        return msg;
    };


    window.WWebJS.getChatModel = async chat => {

        let res = chat.serialize();
        res.isGroup = chat.isGroup;
        res.formattedTitle = chat.formattedTitle;
        res.isMuted = chat.mute && chat.mute.isMuted;

        if (chat.groupMetadata) {
            const chatWid = window.Store.WidFactory.createWid((chat.id._serialized));
            await window.Store.GroupMetadata.update(chatWid);
            res.groupMetadata = chat.groupMetadata.serialize();
        }

        delete res.msgs;
        delete res.msgUnsyncedButtonReplyMsgs;
        delete res.unsyncedButtonReplies;

        return res;
    };

    window.WWebJS.getChat = async chatId => {
        const chatWid = window.Store.WidFactory.createWid(chatId);
        const chat = await window.Store.Chat.find(chatWid);
        return await window.WWebJS.getChatModel(chat);
    };

    window.WWebJS.getChats = async () => {
        const chats = window.Store.Chat.models;

        const chatPromises = chats.map(chat => window.WWebJS.getChatModel(chat));
        return await Promise.all(chatPromises);
    };

    window.WWebJS.getContactModel = contact => {
        let res = contact.serialize();
        res.isBusiness = contact.isBusiness;

        if (contact.businessProfile) {
            res.businessProfile = contact.businessProfile.serialize();
        }

        res.isMe = contact.isMe;
        res.isUser = contact.isUser;
        res.isGroup = contact.isGroup;
        res.isWAContact = contact.isWAContact;
        res.isMyContact = contact.isMyContact;
        res.isBlocked = contact.isContactBlocked;
        res.userid = contact.userid;

        return res;
    };

    window.WWebJS.getContact = async contactId => {
        const wid = window.Store.WidFactory.createWid(contactId);
        const contact = await window.Store.Contact.find(wid);
        return window.WWebJS.getContactModel(contact);
    };

    window.WWebJS.getContacts = () => {
        const contacts = window.Store.Contact.models;
        return contacts.map(contact => window.WWebJS.getContactModel(contact));
    };

    window.WWebJS.mediaInfoToFile = ({ data, mimetype, filename }) => {
        const binaryData = window.atob(data);

        const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(binaryData.length);
        const view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (let i = 0; i < binaryData.length; i++) {
            view[i] = binaryData.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: mimetype });
        return new File([blob], filename, {
            type: mimetype,
            lastModified: Date.now()
        });
    };

    window.WWebJS.arrayBufferToBase64 = (arrayBuffer) => {
        let binary = '';
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        const len = bytes.byteLength;
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }
        return window.btoa(binary);
    };

    window.WWebJS.getFileHash = async (data) => {
        let buffer = await data.arrayBuffer();
        const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', buffer);
        return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)));
    };

    window.WWebJS.generateHash = async (length) => {
        var result = '';
        var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        var charactersLength = characters.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        }
        return result;
    };

    window.WWebJS.sendClearChat = async (chatId) => {
        let chat = window.Store.Chat.get(chatId);
        if (chat !== undefined) {
            await window.Store.SendClear.sendClear(chat, false);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    window.WWebJS.sendDeleteChat = async (chatId) => {
        let chat = window.Store.Chat.get(chatId);
        if (chat !== undefined) {
            await window.Store.SendDelete.sendDelete(chat);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    window.WWebJS.sendChatstate = async (state, chatId) => {
        if (window.Store.Features.features.MD_BACKEND) {
            chatId = window.Store.WidFactory.createWid(chatId);
        }
        switch (state) {
        case 'typing':
            await window.Store.ChatState.sendChatStateComposing(chatId);
            break;
        case 'recording':
            await window.Store.ChatState.sendChatStateRecording(chatId);
            break;
        case 'stop':
            await window.Store.ChatState.sendChatStatePaused(chatId);
            break;
        default:
            throw 'Invalid chatstate';
        }

        return true;
    };

    window.WWebJS.getLabelModel = label => {
        let res = label.serialize();
        res.hexColor = label.hexColor;

        return res;
    };

    window.WWebJS.getLabels = () => {
        const labels = window.Store.Label.models;
        return labels.map(label => window.WWebJS.getLabelModel(label));
    };

    window.WWebJS.getLabel = (labelId) => {
        const label = window.Store.Label.get(labelId);
        return window.WWebJS.getLabelModel(label);
    };

    window.WWebJS.getChatLabels = async (chatId) => {
        const chat = await window.WWebJS.getChat(chatId);
        return (chat.labels || []).map(id => window.WWebJS.getLabel(id));
    };

    window.WWebJS.getOrderDetail = async (orderId, token) => {
        return window.Store.QueryOrder.queryOrder(orderId, 80, 80, token);
    };

    window.WWebJS.getProductMetadata = async (productId) => {
        let sellerId = window.Store.Conn.wid;
        let product = await window.Store.QueryProduct.queryProduct(sellerId, productId);
        if (product && product.data) {
            return product.data;
        }

        return undefined;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

check is whatsapp-web.js is ready status with the code below, if whatsapp-web.js is ready status you will not find error in anymore

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Client is ready!");
});
```